# Cannot hide sibling element with z-index set to 1

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a modal overlaying another element. The close button on the lower element has its z-index set to 1. When I create the modal this original close button is still nested on top of the new modal and its new close button.

I've tried grabbing this element in the dom and hiding it, but since it is not a parent element I do not see how.

**Edit**: This is pseudo code...The question is how to remove an overlaid sibling element.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img style={{z-index: 1; position: fixed;}}>close button (sibling, this one needs to be moved underneath or hidden)</img>
  </div>
<div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img style={{z-index: 1; position: relative;}}>close button (popup modal)</img>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solved**: Turns out I can just grab the element by its id regardless of where it is in the DOM hierarchy (after adding an id) and toggle its display. Not sure why I thought otherwise. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtnSibling');
closeLessonBtn.style.display = 'none';
```

and

```
closeLessonBtn.style.display = null;
```

Comment: That honestly doesn't look like react code at all. Generally for a modal, you'd check this.state to toggle the modal on or off, and the whole thing would be inside a render in the return of your instantiating class. (not enough rep in this community to make this a comment).

Answer (score 1):

`style={z-index: 1; position: fixed;}` -> `style={{zIndex: 1, position: 'fixed'}}`

React inline styles reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? Are you using CSS or SASS for styling by any chance?

Position fixed should always have a width.

for instance:

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; 
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Make sure that HTML and BODY is set to width and height 100%.

Give it a higher index for the fixed close button.

Also, another simple tip would be not to use empty div. Just wrap it with  as a placeholder, this way it will not be outputted in the source while inspecting the element.